# Laravel 4 - eager load doesn't print

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I try to chain three tables in Laravel. My code so far is:

```php
class Ownership extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'games_users';

    public function games() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Game','games_users','owntype_id','games_id');
    }

    public function type() {
        return $this->hasMany('Owntype','id');
    }
}
```

And my controller:

```php
$own = Ownership::with('games','type')->get();
```

With `print_r`, it seems to work, but I can't print it. How can I do it?

**EDIT**

With code

```php
$own = Ownership::with('games','type')->get();

foreach($own as $game) {
    echo $game->games;
}
```

I am getting this:

```php
[{"id":1,"title":"Gra","pivot":{"owntype_id":1,"games_id":1}}][{"id":2,"title":"Gra 2","pivot":{"owntype_id":2,"games_id":2}}]
```

Problems are: I don't know how to echo `title` and it doesn't have nothing from `type` function I did attach.

Comment: Have you tired looping `$own` and using the property name, or getting first row `Ownership::with('games', 'type')->first()` then using property name.

Comment: Yes I did. For `$own = Ownership::with('games','type')->first();` and then "foreaching", it rturns "111". When I try do go with `echo $game->games->title;` I'm getting "Trying to get property of non-object".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and came across your unanswered question, but try `echo $game->games['title']`, as it's an array